# SQLite: Joining two select statements

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two select statements and I am looking for a way to join them into one.  Thank you for any help and advice.

```
Original:
1
2
3
4
5
6

Sql:
Select * From (Select * From tbl1 Where Id < 4 Order By Id Desc Limit 1) Order By Id;
Select * From tbl1 Where Id >= 4 Order By Id;

Result:
3
4
5
6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you could use a [`UNION SELECT`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp).

```
Select * From (Select * From tbl1 Where Id < 4 Order By Id Desc Limit 1)
UNION Select * From tbl1 Where Id >= 4
Order By Id;
```

Works only if the result of the two statements has the same column count and types.

Comment: `UNION ALL` would be more efficient.

Comment: @CL it depends on the desired result. `UNION ALL` contains duplicates. It didn't seem to as if OP would desire such a result.

Comment: @CL you are right. In this case the results are mutually exclusive by themselves. `UNION ALL` would give the same result without having to do a duplicate check. In case performance is not that big of an issue, I still would prefer `UNION` because it expresses the intention of the statement without making assumptions. It would be better readable and maintainable code in my opinion. Still you have a valid point :-)

Answer (score 3):

What's the point in using this:

```
Select * From (Select * From tbl1 Where Id < 4 Order By Id Desc Limit 1) Order By Id;
```

Isn't this enough?:

```
Select * From tbl1 Where Id < 4 Order By Id Desc Limit 1
```

Anyways, you can use SQL `UNION` for this.

```
(SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE Id < 4 ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE Id >= 4 ORDER BY Id ASC)
ORDER BY Id
```

Your first query can be considered as an entire table. Likewise, your 2nd query can be considered as another table.

Then, using the SQL operator `UNION`, you can get a combined resultset, joining those two 'tables'.

For more details, please go through the following link:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: Thank you for the answer and tutorial link.  Could you tell me the difference with UNION or without UNION (answer from Kirill Nay)?

Comment: A clarification: Kirill's query doesn't run in MySQL. MySQL 5.6.17 doesn't support queries with a `IN` along with subqueries which have `LIMIT`. As I'm using MySQL, it's hard for me to make any comparison between my query and that of Kirill's. Sorry for my previous comment.

Comment: I didn't get why you said sorry.  Anyway, as I said the query is for SQLite.  What I would to know is if one is better than the other, this in term of performance and best practices.

Comment: In terms of performance, I guess query without `UNION` is better. In terms of practice, it's by far the easiest and most recommended way.